# How to find the closest to a given number N to the power of X?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Let's say we have a number 4923 and we want to find the closest $n^x$

2 ^ 12 = 4096 but it's not the closest possible  $n^x$, for example 17 ^ 3 = 4913 is closer to 4923

How do we find the closest $n^x$ to a given number without bruteforce? Let's assume it's a positive integer of 4 digits long, as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm which is not brute force:

Given a number $N$ (to which we need to find the closest power)

Consider numbers of the form $$A^{B}$$

For $B \in \{1, 2, \dots, 1+ \lfloor\log_2 N\rfloor]\}$

Fix $B$, then do a binary search for $A$ to figure out which is the closest.

This will be an $O(\log^2 N)$ operations algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Do you happened to know Python? The code would help to understand it, unfortunately my math understanding is limited, I'm not sure what does Fix B means

Comment: @Un1: Something like: `for B in xrange(1, log N + 1):  bin_search(...)`

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea to do a binary search